# Are particular Korean nouns (명사) also classified as determinators (관형사)?

Tags: grammar

For a project I'm doing I'm trying to figure out if the following words are determinators (관형사) or just nouns (명사)?

오늘, 각각, 모두 (not 모든), 이번, 일부

I know that 이, 그, 새, 옛, ... are determinators, but I'm specifically interested in the words I wrote above.

Thanks! :)

Comment: If you go to [Naver Korean Dictionary](https://ko.dict.naver.com/ "Naver Korean Dictionary") and lookup those words, the definition includes the part of speech they are. :)

Comment: First, those are determiners, not determinators. Second, any solid dictionary online or offline contains information about the word's part of speech.

Answer (score 1):

They are all noun, as you can find in dictionary.

I think you can think them as determiner, because it looks like they are used as determiner.

For example: `이번 역은 서울, 서울 역입니다.`(This station is Seoul, Seoul.)

In this sentence, `이번` looks like determiner. But, it is not: it is noun, and `이번 역` is noun phrase(명사구).

Example of noun phrase : `저 성실한 학생` in `저 성실한 학생이 철수이다.`

As you can see in [twitter of national institute of Korean language](https://twitter.com/urimal365/status/555223627348447232), Noun can modify following noun.

Additionally, `의`(genitive postposition) can be skipped randomly, like `서울의 하늘`(Sky of Seoul) and `서울 하늘`(Seoul sky),`오늘의 할 일의 목록`(List of to-do of today), `오늘의 할 일 목록`(To-do list of today), and `오늘 할 일 목록`(Today to-do list)

And, about difference of determiner and noun. When you find `오늘` in Korean dictionary, it means `지금 지나가고 있는 이날`(the day passing now). and `새` in Korean dictionary, `이미 있던 것이 아니라 처음 마련하거나 다시 생겨난`(regenerated or newly prepared, not had gotten already). Can see the difference? ( -(으)ㄴ is sign of adjective clause (Wikipedian expression, or determiner clause).

And as I mentioned in comment, noun can be followed by postposition(조사), whereas determiner can't. Like : `오늘은 피곤하다`(today is tired, or I'm tired today). But, `옛에는 그러곤 했다` is wrong sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I did look up at Naver, I just don't understand why they are not considered determiners in Korean if they 'work' like determiners (under the English definition of determiners). There is such a thing as 한정사, so why for example in Korean 이번 역 is a noun phrase where 이번 is a noun rather than a 한정사? Is there a different definition for this POS (determiner) in Korean?

Comment: @hangug_wannabe ["Nouns can act as premodifiers in noun phrases"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/noun-phrases/noun-phrases-dependent-words) just as in English. The main difference between 관형사 and 명사 is that 관형사 cannot be used independently whereas 명사 can.

Comment: @hangug_wannabe There is no `한정사` in Korean. I searched [Naver Korean dictionary about `한정사`](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/7dda2eb244e740daaabe11ffe76f5724) and here is what I got. `...‘이/가/는/를’까지 서양 말의 관사에 견주어 ‘한정사’로 보는 학자도 있다.`(there is some scholars who think `이/가/는/를` as `한정사` compare with article of western language.)  Determiner in Korean is `관형사`.

Comment: @hangug_wannabe Let's see. 이번 is noun, and think about determiner `순`(pure) to compare. We can say like`이번에는 다 잘 될 것이다` (Everything will fine this time), `이번은 아니다`(Not this time). You can see `이번` is followed by `에는` or `은`.  They are 조사(postposition), which following 명사(noun) or some of 부사(adverb). But, we cannot say something like this with `순`. Determiner cannot be followed by postposition.

Comment: Oh, I see. Very interesting. So from your answer I understand that there are different rules that define determiner in Korean versus English (?). Because by English point of view, it is natural to assume that 이번 is a determiner. But it is not, because as you said, it can be followed by a postposition. Thank you so much for your kind reply!

Comment: @hangug_wannabe Because it *can* be followed by postposition. Also, I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry. My mistake. I edited that now. Thanks for the correction.